# C# Wrong Loop On My DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

Good day, I'm having an error. I choose the August 5, 2015 on the date picker with the loop count of 3. But I'm having a problem. I'm using add 15 prior to the given output. But the first count is wrong.

#### THE OUTPUT IN THE FIRST COUNT IS

```
8/20/2015
but it should be 
8/05/2015 because I use the 8/05/2015 on the datepicker.
```

I don't know what's the problem here.

Here's my code (This will be execute when the button "Calculate Schedule" is click"

```
private void execute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var fromDate = date_from.Value; // Getting the value from DatePicker

   int count;

   for (count = 0; count < 3; count++) {
      dgv_result.Rows.Add(1);
            int numrows = count + 1;

            fromDate = fromDate.AddDays(15); 

            dgv_result.Rows[count].Cells[1].Value = numrows; // Just for numbering the rows
            dgv_result.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value = fromDate.ToShortDateString();
   }
}
```

Here's my Screenshot

#### NOTE: Just check the Month only

[image]

Comment: Where are you adding 15?

Comment: I meant, where in the code. You didn't mention here.

Comment: Do you set the data_from's value  in other function?

Comment: First and the most important, you should Not work directly with DataGridView but the model behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to put this line at the end of the loop:

```
for (count = 0; count < 3; count++) 
{
    dgv_result.Rows.Add(1);
    int numrows = count + 1;

    dgv_result.Rows[count].Cells[1].Value = numrows; // Just for numbering the rows
    dgv_result.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value = fromDate.ToShortDateString();

    //add days after adding the row, so next line will be effected by it
    fromDate = fromDate.AddDays(15); 
}
```

I am considering you're not using `fromDate` anywhere else and it is just for the loop.

Comment: Its working sir!!! :D Thank you sir.! Thanks for the new learning, Yeah. The loop read the first run that's why when I put it on the middle, it already reads the fromDate. :D God bless you sir! Amen!

Comment: Sir, I have another question :) I think its just simple for you.

Comment: If your problem is related to this question, edit this question, other wise  ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding days before you write your first row. So you need to `.AddDays(15)` at the end line of for loop.